# Running new rails app *and* legacy app on top of the same database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

I'm working on a project where we're building several new rails apps that are intended to be launched running along side a legacy app that will need to use the same database. The legacy database uses Oracle.

I believe it would be ideal to just cut-over cleanly and not have both the new and legacy apps running on the same db, but in this case it's simply not possible. The legacy app is too large and runs a pretty complex system that's the core of the business. The intention is to replace it a bit at a time.

But to do that will require that we launch rails apps each handling part of the application -- and sharing the database with the currently operating legacy app.

I've looked around quite a bit and haven't been able find any definitive rails docs describing what issues we might run into -- or even if it's possible. I know that Heroku now supports running multiple rails apps pointing at a single database. I've found lots of discussion on people doing this, but nothing that really pinpoints where the potential risks are.

Is this possible? What specific problems are likely to occur?

EDIT: To clarify, the legacy application is not rails-based. It's based on some completely different technology.

Answer (score 1):

While this is possible, you'll have to be very careful, especially if you have two systems performing migrations on the same tables.

Ideally one application "owns" the database and assumes the responsibility for migrating the various tables, but it's possible to split this so that some tables are owned by one application and some by the other. The `schema_migrations` table should be able to track these independently.

You will run into trouble if you have to make modifications to the same table in both applications as there will be no way to ensure one modification is made before the other, the migration chains are independent.

If you're careful to avoid this sort of thing, it's usually fine.

Be sure you have a robust test environment to simulate what happens when both applications are exercised in tandem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this situation, the legacy application will continue operating as it is, while the new application will eventually take overall the functionality in the old one -- at which point the legacy app will be retired. So one of them can't be the only one that does updates to data; they both must create, update and delete the same kinds of data.

Comment: What @tadman is talking about is modification to the schema/structure of the DB. Changes to the actual data will still follow whatever locking/isolation levels that are set in the apps. So standard CRUD stuff shouldn't pose an issue.

Comment: Like what @Doon says, modifying *data* is okay. Modifying the *schema*, where you're adding and removing columns and so forth, will lead to complications if you're not careful. If application A assumes control over the schema for some of the tables and B assumes control over the remainder, you'll be okay. Just be sure application A isn't introducing data into the system that application B can't understand, or where application A's validations conflict with B leading to update problems.

Comment: Ah, yes I see. I misread. And I agree that schema migration issues will need to be managed carefully.